# Why is Fluent Validation's IsEmpty rule triggered for my `Id` property that has a value of zero?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation, business-rules

I have a view model `ApplicantProfileModel` that works in all respects. It declares a property

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

and this property is present in a partial view like this

```
@model Comair.RI.UI.Models.ApplicantProfileModel
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend></legend>
    <ul class="form-column">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    .....
```

I have the following Fluent Validation rule for this property:

```
RuleFor(p => p.Id).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Id is empty. Messsage may have been tampered with.");
```

An `int` with a value of zero is certainly not 'empty'. I know I can change the rule to not equal to zero, but that doesn't solve my problem and answer my question as to why an `int` of value `0` is considered empty by fluent validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because an `int` is a value type and can't not have a value. Under the hood `FluentValidation` checks against `default` for that type, which I believe would be 0 for `int`. If you can make your `Id` a nullable int you can get that behaviour. Otherwise I would do as you suggest and check for not equal to 0.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I think I'll use Nullable<int>, because a new entity shouldn't have an Id before being posted to the 'save' action.